# Why does ngOnChanges take time. Is it asynchronous?

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10

I am using angular 9+ and i am little confused of the behavior of ngOnChanges life cycle.

**What I am trying to do**

I have a asynchrounous operation which sets a value (Object type) to the child component using @Input() decorator. The code is as below. (Stackblitz [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jjxkzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts))

**parent.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;
  data = { value: null };

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const foo = of([1])
      .pipe(delay(500))
      .subscribe(subscriber => {
        this.data = { value: 123 };
        this.childComponent.printState();
      });
  }
}
```

**Parent.Html**

```
<app-child [data]="data"></app-child>
```

**Child Component**

```
    import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data = null;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges');
  }

  printState() {
    console.log('printState');
    console.log(this.data.value);
  }
}
```

What i am trying to is , as soon as i change the value, i am trying to print the value of the set value by using a view child reference as shown above.

Ideally the sequence should have been

```
ngOnChanges // initial value
ngOnChanges // after value set
printState // after calling printState()
```

but i see

```
ngOnChanges 
printState 
ngOnChanges
```

in the console which is pretty consfusing. Why is ngOnChanges nor fired immediately. Why is it taking time. Can someone explain.

Thanks and stay safe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update any variable bound to `@Input()` as you are doing in `ngAfterViewInit` of `AppComponent` , the change detection will be scheduled by Angular to run just [before view rendering](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12e0cfab54a58e46c157b2e840520847e30cdd28/packages/elements/src/component-factory-strategy.ts#L258) and not immediately after assignment.

Hence, the code in `ngAfterViewInit` will execute first, and code in `ngOnChanges` will be invoked by Angular in next tick.

Yes, in summary, change detection is asynchronous.

Comment: why ngOnChanges has to be scheduled ? I thought only asynchrounous code gets scheduled. Isnt ngOnChanges supposed to be synchronous ?

Comment: Updated my answer - yes, the ngOnChanges code is executed by Angular asychronously.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you :)